# Tensorflow:Unable to visualize embeddings in word2vec_basic.py?

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, tensorflow, word2vec

I am trying to implement tensorflows [word2vec_basic.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) model in my system.I went through this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec/) to understand and implement it.

After I ran the word2vec code using python3 in my system it asked me to install sklearn, matplotlib, and scipy to visualize embeddings.

So I installed sklearn, matplotlib, and scipy using pip in my system and ran the code a second time but it still asks me to install the above 3 again.

No errors were there during installation of sklearn, matplotlib, and scipy. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

[image: Here is the screen shot]

UPDATE: Here is the screenshot after removing `try` and `except` - 
https://ibin.co/377XsooeSdej.png

Comment: What command are you using to run your TensorFlow project?

Comment: I did not  get you martianwars. what command are you talking about

Comment: Are you running `word2vec` using `python3`?

Comment: yes i am using python3

Comment: What's the version of `scikit-learn`?

Comment: `TSNE` is the problem, I'd faced this too. Have a look at the answer

Comment: i am using scikit version 0.18.1

Comment: I'm not completely sure of my answer though, since my version was 0.14.1
If it doesn't work, remove the last `try` `except` from the code and show me the stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As evident from the error message, you are missing the `python3-tk` package. Try to install it using,

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Comment: Let's be completely sure, could you remove the `try` `except` and show me the output?

Comment: Don't remove the blocks -_- just the keywords so that the error is seen on terminal

Comment: Also, if the code is taking too much time, reduce the iterations

Comment: That's not possible if you got an error with the try catch. Show me the last part of your code once? Did the graph come up?

Comment: Do you understand what `try` does? You need to remove the indent from the code under try

Comment: without try and except i had this error https://imagebin.ca/v/377XsooeSdej

Comment: I installed python3-tk but i am still getting this https://imagebin.ca/v/377h2QmjwB6w without try and except

Comment: Send the output after removing `try`, `except`. Did you see a graph come up?

Comment: should i remove the complete block or just the keyword

Comment: Please understand what `try` `except` is doing. Remove the `try` keyword, unindent the `try` block, remove `except` keyword, remove the `except` block. Mention if you see a graph

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong .. try is calling TSNE a tool to visualize high dimensional data right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131863/discussion-between-martianwars-and-aniruddh).